# Haskell for a server?

Tags: haskell, erlang

With regards to making a game server, it seems Erlang always comes up as a language that is "built for this kind of thing" with its scalability and concurrency features. I don't have experience in either Haskell nor Erlang, but on the surface they seem the same. Looking into Haskell's docs it seems like it has support for multiprocessor scalability and concurrency, and Haskell is said to be a more solid language and has a visibly better community. My question is, then, is Haskell considered to be as good of a solution to server building as Erlang supposedly is?

Comment: Haskell was born before the net. Erlang by an telecom company.

Comment: Haskell was defined in 1990. C++ was designed by a telecom as well.

Comment: https://code.facebook.com/posts/745068642270222/fighting-spam-with-haskell/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with your server.  As might be expected from a telecoms application, **Erlang excels at doing simple tasks with very high concurrency**.  If your server will need a bazillion connections per second, or at once, Erlang is your friend.  Erlang also offers better support for distributing load over multiple servers.

**Haskell excels at complex, symbolic computation** and as of April 2009 can also handle a great many threads (see update below).  Moreover, Haskell has **more tools for getting complicated code right**: things like [QuickCheck](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/), [SmallCheck](http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/smallcheck/), and the static type system.  So if your server is doing complicated, interesting things and you can get by with just one server, you're probably better off with Haskell.

---

**Update 13 April 2009**: Don Stewart, a reliable source, reports that "the last thread-scaling bug in the Glasgow Haskell Compiler was squished a few months ago", and that some users report using a million Haskell threads without trouble. As of January 2009, there is a [new, unpublished paper from the implementors](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/parallel/) which may describe how this is achieved.

---

**Update 21 February 2012**: John Hughes's company, [QuviQ](http://quviq.com), now makes QuickCheck for Erlang.  They have found a number of very interesting bugs.  You can download "QuickCheck Mini" for free; it is comparable to the Haskell QuickCheck.  There is also a more powerful commercial version.

Comment: can you give some evidence for your claim about Haskell hitting a wall wrt threads sooner?  With OS threads, perhaps... but what about Haskell threads?

Comment: my Erlang bubble burst a bit when I saw this: http://www.nabble.com/Chameneos.rednux-micro-benchmark-td19925134.html ... I verified the results on my boxes and they are correct, there seems to be some huge issue with SMP scalability and messaging. The GHC implementation performs much better...

Comment: @ja: All my evidence comes from hallway conversations with the Erlang and GHC guys at ICFP (http://icfpconference.org).  It is true that the GHC guys have spent the last year really gearing up for multicore and parallelism, whereas my impression is Erlang is now more in a commercialization phase.

Comment: GHC's last (?) thread scaling issue was squished a few months ago, and there's been a few reports of million+ threads without trouble. That said, the Erlang focus is much more on distribution, rather than shared-mem multicore.

Comment: I think I should point out that Erlang also has Quickcheck, and it is even slightly more evolved than the Haskell version. Both Erlang QC and Haskell QC is made by the same person but EQC is now even commercial.

Comment: That's a really nice summary of what the two respective languages are good at, and where their strengths lie.

Answer (score 10):

The benchmarks of these papers show that Haskell can compete with Apache:

[*Developing a high-performance web server in Concurrent Haskell*](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/bib.html)

— Simon Marlow

[*Combining Events And Threads For Scalable Network Services:
Implementation And Evaluation Of Monadic,
Application-level Concurrency Primitives*](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1391&context=cis_papers)

— Peng Li Stephan A. Zdancewic (see Figure 19)

Comment: Unfortunately Marlow's paper isn't publicly available anymore

Comment: Fixed.  Thx for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9):

> I don't have experience in either Haskell nor Erlang, but on the surface they seem the same.

There are some pretty stark differences between Haskell and Erlang. Erlang is specifically designed for concurrent systems. The language and virtual machine are both designed to support many, many processes, and Erlang uses an actor-style system to manage communication between all of them. Haskell also supports concurrency fairly easily, due to its functional nature, *but* it's still a bit harder to do concurrent programming in Haskell, and the language isn't specifically set up to facilitate this.

Like Haskell, Erlang doesn't share state between processes, so it's easy to write multi-process software. But the programming style between Haskell and Erlang is a bit different, since Erlang emphasizes the use of small processes to perform concurrent processing.

I love Haskell -- it's one of my favorite languages -- but if I was going to write server software, I'd probably use Erlang. But it's certainly possible to write a server in Haskell, if you know Haskell better or find the library support to be superior.

Comment: > it's actually a logic programming language

No, it is not. There is no built-in search, you can't work with uninitialized variables, no full unification, etc.

The syntax is Prolog-ish, and pattern-matching permits using the same variable on the left side (not on the right!), but it's functional.

Answer (score 8):

Now there is a new option: [use the Haskell/Erlang FFI to write your logic in Haskell and communicate using Erlang](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Interfacing_other_languages/Erlang).

Answer (score 7):

Last time I looked, the libraries and frameworks for building scalable servers in Erlang looked a bit more mature than those for Haskell. I'd suggest looking at [*Programming Erlang: Software for a Concurrent World*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435600X) for information on those.

Answer (score 7):

It is a lot easier to introduce memory leaks in your Haskell application due to laziness. Long-running servers are *precisely* the kind of programs where you *really* don't want to have any memory leaks.

While I agree that Haskell is a more solid language and nicer to program in, Erlang is much easier and has many libraries specifically intended for uses like these.

I don't think there is a Haskell equivalent to, say, Mnesia, and writing it is going to be difficult. You *can* write Haskell versions of `gen_server`, `gen_event`, etc. but they won't have been optimised and tuned for over a decade.

Comment: Actually, memory leaks are impossible to introduce without using the FFI or something similar: all memory is accounted for by the garbage collector and can be recovered.

What you are referring to are "space leaks," which means memory used for unevaluated thunks. Just evaluating them (or throwing them away) will free the memory.

That said, dealing with this issue, since it's entirely unfamiliar to most programmers, takes a fair amount of work at first, and you should plan for it.

Comment: Curt is absolutely right, a space leak is technically not the same as a memory leak, but they will behave the same way in many programs that iterate indefinitely.  I would say that it is *much* easier to unwittingly introduce a space leak in a Haskell program than a memory leak in a C program, since it requires careful attention to lazy evaluation order, which is often unintuitive. That said I'm a Haskell noob -- I presume it gets easier with practice.

Answer (score 5):

The question of whether Haskell is as good as Erlang depends on what people want from a language. I think both would do quite well as a game server, but it depends mainly on what you want or expect from a programming language. One of the easiest differences to note is that Haskell is a statically typed language with type inference, and Erlang is a dynamically typed language. Overall, I would say that Haskell requires a bit more "sophistication" for those not accustomed to functional programming.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you can find people who think so, but I think you're mistaken about the ability of Erlang to support this kind of use; it's widely used in telephony applications, and is actually quite robust.  Erlang is very much optimized to highly reliable, high concurrency servers.

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused by your reply - you start off saying I'm mistaken that Erlang can be used for something like making a game server, then ou finish by saying its optimized to handle reliable, concurrent servers?